# Most commented posts by time period (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have this code which works great.

```
 <?php 
      $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 25"); // NUMBER OF POSTS
         foreach ($result as $topten) {
             $postid = $topten->ID;
             $title = $topten->post_title;
             $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
             if ($commentcount != 0) {
      ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"><span class="tags"> <?php echo $title ?></span></a>
   
   <?php } } ?>
```

Now it displays (order) the most popular posts by comment count (ALL-TIME).

I know that WordPress understands command 'period':

```
   period=1hourago
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the above code working with the period, so that I could define:

24hoursago

or

12hoursago

and so on...

I know I need to somehow integrate this into code:

```
 'date_query' => [
        [
           
        ]
    ],
```

But I can't seem to find a way of putting all togheter.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your SQL query to use a JOIN statement to search the comments table for items within a timeframe and refactored your code to move the comment count check into the query:

```
 // Target timeframe
$time   = time();
$range  = strtotime('-6 hours', $time);

// Convert to GMT to match DB
$start  =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$end    =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

// Update with comment table search and post comment count
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT p.comment_count, p.ID, p.post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
        JOIN $wpdb->comments AS c
            ON ( p.ID = c.comment_post_ID )
    WHERE c.comment_date < '$start' AND c.comment_date > '$end'
    AND p.comment_count > 0
    ORDER BY p.comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 25"
);

foreach ($result as $topten) {
    $link = get_permalink( $topten->ID );
    $title = $topten->post_title;
    printf ( "<a href='%s'><span class='tags'>'%s</span></a>", $link,  $title );
}
```

You can also search on a date like so:

```
    $start  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2007-11-21'));
    $end    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2007-11-21 -24 hours'));
```